# wordpress submenu cannot toggle due to inappropriate jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to build a phone responsive wordpress menu. The submenu cannot showup after click. I need some help from jquery. Thanks in advance.

This is the php:

```
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-12975" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-item-12975"><a href="#">Context</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-12981" class="menu-item menu-item-12981"><a href="#">a</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-12984" class="menu-item menu-item-12984"><a href="#">b</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-12985" class="menu-item menu-item-12985"><a href="#">c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-42"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is the js:

```
(function($) {
$('.nav-menu .sub-menu').parent().on( 'click', function() {
        var $this = $( this );
        $this.attr( 'aria-pressed', function( index, value ) {
            return 'false' === value ? 'true' : 'false';
        });

        $this.toggleClass( 'activated' );
        $this.next( '.nav-menu .sub-menu' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );

    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1049px) {
    .nav-menu .sub-menu{
        display: none!important;
    }

    .nav-menu .sub-menu.activated { 
        display: block!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the attr aria-pressed?? please explain well what you need .. you want when click on anchor  show the ul list inside the li??

Comment: Yes, I want to click on "context", then the sub-menu part will be displayed. Normally, the sub-menu should be hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you need I think

```
(function($) {
$('.nav-menu .sub-menu').prev('a').on( 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $( this );
        $this.attr( 'aria-pressed', function( index, value ) {
            return 'false' === value ? 'true' : 'false';
        });

        $this.closest('li').find( '.sub-menu' ).slideToggle( 'fast' ).toggleClass( 'activated' );

    });
})(jQuery);
```

in css

```
@media (max-width: 1049px) {
    .nav-menu .sub-menu{
        display: none!important;
    }

    .nav-menu .sub-menu.activated { 
      /*-----^------*/
       display: block!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: @thodison Good luck :) .. finally be sure that   $this.attr( 'aria-pressed'   will work with anchor not with li  <a aria-pressed="true"></a> if you will use it for li  just use  $this.closest('li').attr( 'aria-pressed'    to be <li aria-pressed="true"><a></a></li> ..

Answer (score 0):

To make this code working I think you should change the css as following:

```
.activated .nav-menu.sub-menu { 
    display: block!important;
}
```

From your jQuery part of the code `$this` will point on the `.sub-menu` parent element. Hence, `activated` class changing affects the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in the click handler

`$this.toggleClass( 'activated' )` 
to 
`$this.children('.sub-menu').toggleClass( 'activated' )`

Since `this` inside click referes to the parent which is not the `.sub-menu` so the class `.activated` is not added correctly.

And there is a typo in your css code you need a space here `.nav-menu.sub-menu.activated` so it should look like this `.nav-menu .sub-menu.activated`.

[Here](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/YyjdKX?editors=001) is the working example.

Comment: @thodison in what way does it not work? are there any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Thanks. It works but not in phones. When the css is wraped with "@media (max-width: 1049px)", it will not work.

Comment: @thodison if you want it work across all devices the media query is redudant anyways, if the question helped be sure to mark it as the right one.